# how do I check if openCv is already loaded?

Tags: java, linux, opencv, tomcat

i have this line code in my java program to load openCV

```
static {
    nu.pattern.OpenCV.loadShared();
}
```

When I first deploy to tomcat hosted on linux server it works fine.  But on subsequent redeploys, I get an error message saying the library has already been loaded.  I have to shutdown and startup tomcat again to get it to work.
What should I do in this situation?

Comment: Post the stacktrack